# submitting form in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, iframe

I'm having an iframe in my page where I load content of the website with fade effect.
In order to handle form submits inside the iframe I created this function:

```
$("#coll").contents().find("form input[type=submit").bind("click",function(event)
{
      event.preventDefault();
      element=$(this).parent("form");

      if (element.attr("action") === "") {
            $("#coll").fadeOut("slow",function()
            {
                element.submit();
            });
      }
      else {
            var page = element.attr("action");
            $("#coll").fadeOut("slow", function()
            {
                $('#coll').attr("src",page);
            });
       }
       return false;
});
```

The problem is that if the form has an action the new page is loaded, however values of the form are not sent. Where is the problem?

Forms with empty action are running with no problems.

Comment: Is this your code exactly? If so, "form input[type=submit" is missing another "]". You should also post your HTML so we can have more context.

Comment: do you use $('#coll').attr("src",page); to load another page? if so it explains why form values are missing - the form wasn't submitted as in case of action attribute missing.

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot Thanks, i solved that, but it seems it's not the problem.

Comment: @Dmitry actually i use $('#coll').attr("src",page); if there is an action, check the code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only call submit if the form *doesn't* have an action. If it does have an action you only set src to the action page - this doesn't submit the form it just changes the url. You need to  call `element.submit()` in the `else` clause.

Comment: when i changed that, nothing is happening when i click the submit button

Comment: You have to **submit** a form to post data. I don't have your code to test it out so I can't tell you exactly what code will fix the problem, but I *can* tell you that simply changing the src won't submit a form so thats is where the problem is. If nothing happens then you're probably getting a javascript error - that causes jquery to just stop. Check the console to see what the error is. But you *have* to submit a form to post the data!